# SQL - Trigger UPDATE con datos de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, ssms

Tengo problemas para crear un trigger en SQL que me permita actualizar la totalidad de datos desde tabla idéntica.
Tengo 3 DB con idéntica arquitectura, son de un software de gestión y cada una es una empresa distinta.
Lo que quiero es que al modificar una tabla en la empresa principal, esta se modifique en las empresas satélite.

Ya he probado con distintas vías, pero con ninguna lo logro. Actualmente probé este código.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER TR_ActualizaProductos
ON db1.productos
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE db2.productos 
    SET (column1, column2, column3...)
    VALUES(inserted.column1, inserted.column2, inserted.column3...)
    FROM inserted WHERE db2.productos.CodigoProducto = inserted.CodigoProducto
END
```

Ojalá me puedan ayudar

Comment: ¿Usas MySQL? ¿Nos pasas parte del dataset para comprobar que el trigger funciona correctamente?

Comment: @DavidJP Utilizo SSMS, 2017. Aún así te interesa el dataset?
No alcanzo a crear el trigger de Update.

Comment: Te añado las etiquetas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola muy aparte de que update no tiene una propiedad `VALUES` el sql server no manda como objeto row, lo modificado sino como table.

Entendido esto, si o si tienes que hacer un join.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TR_ActualizaProductos
ON db1.productos
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE db2.productos 
    SET p.column1 = i.column1,
        p.column2 = i.column2,
        p.column3 = i.column3,
        p.column4 = i.column4
    FROM db2.productos p
         inner join inserted i
            on p.CodigoProducto = i.CodigoProducto
END
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, el único cambió que debí aplicar, fue quitar el alias "p." en la sentencia SET, pero el funcionó de maravillas. Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La sentencia `UPDATE` no está compuesta por la cláusula `VALUES`, debes especificar cada campo con su correspondiente valor.

Algo así:

```
UPDATE db2.productos 
SET column1 = inserted.column1, column2 = inserted.column2, column3 = inserted.column3
WHERE db2.productos.CodigoProducto = inserted.CodigoProducto
```

Comment: Recibo mensaje "The multi-part identifier "inserted.CodProd" could not be bound."

Comment: Añadí un DECLARE y SET @CodigoProducto = inserted.CodigoProducto pero luego cada uno de los campos inserted.columnN "recibo could not be bound."